# Admin user to update an order status

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: order
```

I have `Admin::OrdersController` and `Clients::OrdersController`

From the clients part the user create his order

From the admin part the admin can change the order's status

My orders status are set like this in the order model:

```
 enum status: [:pending, :paid, :sent, :cancelled, :refunded]
```

To update this status in my **admin/orders/show.html.erb**

I added a form:

```
  <%= form_tag(@order , url: admin_order_path(@order) )do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :status, 2 %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :sub_total, @order.sub_total %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @order.user.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :token, @order.token %>
    <%= submit_tag "Order sent" , class: "btn btn-success"%>
  <% end %>
```

**admin/orders_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @orders = Order.all
        @orders = @orders.filter_by_status(params[:status]) if params[:status]
    end

    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit 
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
        @order.update_attributes(order_params)
        redirect_to @order
    end

    private

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:status,  :user_id, :token , :sub_total)
    end
end
```

request params:

```
 Request
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EmHbw3XMNr1hdhQKXGoMeoSQY82kxLty1M9pJZBHngJgnHY5T9I54gW+iwlww+v+WmmdSXSELLOeNRyCwIjgVQ==",
 "status"=>"2",
 "sub_total"=>"30",
 "user_id"=>"1",
 "token"=>"70717163067e1c9d",
 "commit"=>"Order sent",
 "id"=>"7"}
```

logs

```
Started PATCH "/admin/orders/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-07 16:19:43 +0100
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/nellyduclos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by Admin::OrdersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EmHbw3XMNr1hdhQKXGoMeoSQY82kxLty1M9pJZBHngJgnHY5T9I54gW+iwlww+v+WmmdSXSELLOeNRyCwIjgVQ==", "status"=>"2", "sub_total"=>"30", "user_id"=>"1", "token"=>"70717163067e1c9d", "commit"=>"Order sent", "id"=>"7"}
  [1m[36mOrder Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/orders_controller.rb:17
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: order):

app/controllers/admin/orders_controller.rb:25:in `order_params'
app/controllers/admin/orders_controller.rb:18:in `update'
```

Comment: pls attach the logs for the request, including the params

Comment: i've updated with logs and params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `hidden_field_tag` that does not prefix your params correctly with `order[...]` and because of that `params[:order]` is empty.

Use [`f.hidden_field`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) instead:

```
  <%= form_tag(@order , url: admin_order_path(@order) )do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: 2 %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sub_total, :sub_total %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :token, :token %>
    <%= f.submit "Order sent" , class: "btn btn-success"%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: that was helpful, I actually only need  this field `<%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "sent" %>`

Comment: good! please, consider upvoting also, as it is (even) more valuable to me that accepting